# npm script error while trying to install react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, npm, compiler-errors, npm-install, npm-scripts

While working on my react project, I just tried to install react-router-dom and somehow it seems it erased all my scripts and modules. Now I cannot run the server again no matter what I do. I also cleaned working directories and even deleted the branch, but it still doesn't work at all..
[image]

and below is the error message when I hit 'npm start'.

[image]

Comment: Please add error and other details as text so that it is searchable and others benefit from it in future.

Comment: ok I will. thanks fot the info!

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know why installing react-router-dom removed all my packages, I reinstalled node modules and now it works again. :)